# Unable to access text input element in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

(I'm a relative beginner in chrome-extension development and to StackOverflow so bear with me)

I have a chrome extension that has a text input in the popup. I'm trying to obtain a "real-time" text data feed from the input field.

My JS (popup.js) and HTML (popup.html):

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(evt) {

  document.getElementById("input_field").onkeyup = function() {
    let inputValue = document.getElementById("input_field").value;
    alert(inputValue);
    someAction(inputValue);
  }

});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
</head>

<body>

  <input type="text" id="input_field" placeholder="Blank"/>

  <div id = "root">
    <p> Some Text </p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

My manifest.json:

```
{
"name": "SampleFormApp",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Sample Text",
"manifest_version": 2,
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "assets/icon.png",
    "default_title": "Sample",
    "default_popup": "src/html/popup.html"
},
"background": {
  "scripts": ["src/js/popup.js"],
  "persistent": false
},
"permissions": ["storage", "unlimitedStorage", "tabs", "<all_urls>"],
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "css": ["src/css/styles.css"]
}]
```

}

However, when I try to run the extension, I get this error in the debug log: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onkeyup' of null (from this line: document.getElementById("input_field").onkeyup = function() {).

From my understanding, the "input_field" element from the extension page (popup.html) is null and that is throwing me an error. What should I do to solve this? (I also am not too experienced with jQuery.)

Comment: The background script declared in manifest.json runs in a hidden separate background page, not in the popup, so you need to remove this part from the manifest and instead load the script using the standard script tag with src=popup.js. Might wanna read the intro in the official documentation that describes the architecture.

Comment: Thanks! That totally worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As wOxxOm stated in the comments, I deleted the background scripts section in my manifest.json and added a standard src tag (src=popup.js).